# JBoss 5.1.0 Adding Queues

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, jboss5.x, jboss-messaging

How do I add custom queues to JBoss 5.1.0?

I found a way to do it via the Admin Console however for some reason it keeps failing, also I need to be able to quickly and easily move my queues from one JBoss Server to another.

So basically I was wondering if there is a way to create custom queues in an xml file and add that file to the deploy folder much like how you can do with a custom datasource file (mydatasource-ds.xml).

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Create a file ending with *destinations-service.xml* under your instance's *deploy* directory (or *deploy/messaging* if you like), e.g. *my-jms-destinations-service.xml*. It should look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Messaging Destinations deployment descriptor.
-->
<server>

  <mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService"
         name="jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=MyQueue"
         xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml">
    <attribute name="JNDIName">MyQueue</attribute>
    <depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends>
    <depends>jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice</depends>
  </mbean>

</server>
```

Set the mbean name and JNDI name as required. Add more mbean definitions for additional queues, or split them across multiple **destinstations-service.xml* files for easily deploying / undeploying queues independently of each other.

Answer (score 1):

this may come a little late, but I also had a few errors when creating queues through the Admin console.

The error was due to a missing folder named queue inside the deploy folder. After creating the queue folder, I was able to create the queues using the admin console.